# Python - how to connect word with iteration

Tags: python, class, iteration

I'm making class for people and their names. I want to make specific name for each one like:

obj0, obj1, obj2... + obji

im trying to do this in iteration. Which sign could I use to connect 'obj' and 'i'?

```
for i in range(100):
    name=input('Your name:')
    obji=Person(name)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to actually be pythonic (or really, just not insane enough to make 100 variables), you could make a `list`.

```
obj = []
for i in range(100):
    name=input('Your name:')
    obj.append(Person(name))
```

If you want to set the size of your list before your loop so you can access it with `i`, you can do something like this

```
obj = [None] * 100
for i in range(100):
    name=input('Your name:')
    obj[i] = Person(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to make variables like this on the fly, instead you can use a dictionary for example

```
people = {}
for i in range(100):
    name = input('Your name:')
    people[i] = name
```

Then you can look them up like

```
people[7]
```

Although if they are just going to be sequential, instead of a `dict` you could just use a `list`

```
people = []
for i in range(100):
    people.append(input('Your name: '))
```

You could then still look people up the same way

```
people[7]
```

Answer (score 0):

rather than trying to create separate, related names, why not put them in a list:

```
objs=[]
for i in range(100):
    name = input("Your Name? ")
    objs.append(Person(name)
```